# Kubernetes assign pods to pool

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

is there a way to tell kubectl that my pods should only deployed on a certain instance pool?

For example:

```
nodeSelector:
      pool: poolname
```

Assumed i created already my pool with something like:

```
gcloud container node-pools create poolname --cluster=cluster-1 --num-nodes=10 --machine-type=n1-highmem-32
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Ok, i found out a solution:

gcloud creates a label for the pool name. In my manifest i just dropped that under the node selector. Very easy.

Here comes my manifest.yaml: i deploy ipyparallel with kubernetes

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ipengine
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ipengine
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ipengine
        image: <imageaddr.>
        args:
        - ipengine
        - --ipython-dir=/tmp/config/
        - --location=ipcontroller.default.svc.cluster.local
        - --log-level=0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            #memory: 3Gi
      nodeSelector:
        #<labelname>:value
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: pool-highcpu32
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **taints** and **tolerations**. That way, you don't have to know/hardcode the specific pool name, but simply that it will have the **taint** `high-cpu`, for example. Then you give your pods a **tolerance** for that taint, and they can schedule on that target pool.

That allows you to have multiple pools, or to have HA pool deployment, where you can migrate from one pool to another by changing the taints on the pools.

The *gotcha* here, however, is that while a toleration allows pods to schedule on a tainted pool, it won't prevent them from scheduling elsewhere. So, you've need to taint `pool-a` with `taint-a`, and `pool-b` with `taint-b`, and give pods for `pool-a` and `pool-b` the proper taints to keep them out of eachother's pools.

Comment: An example would make your answer more helpful. In case anyone is interested in this solution (which I believe is better) refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Digital ocean Kubernetes](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/) you have access to the labels below for every node pool.

```
doks.digitalocean.com/node-id
doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool
doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool-id
```

You can use [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) with any of the provided labels. The first label allows one to assign a deployment to a particular node while the last two targets the node pool.

I will say targeting the NodePool is preferable instead of a specific pods as pods can be destroyed and new ones created. Quick example below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ipengine
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ipengine
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ipengine
        image: <imageaddr.>
        args:
        - ipengine
        - --ipython-dir=/tmp/config/
        - --location=ipcontroller.default.svc.cluster.local
        - --log-level=0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1
            #memory: 3Gi
      nodeSelector:
        doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool: pool-highcpu32
```

The label `doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool` expects the pool name as value and you can also use `doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool-id` which expects the id of the pool as value.

Answer (score 1):

Or you do both!

- use **labels** to select which pool to run on
- use **taints** and **tolerations** to ensure that **only** other pods don't try to run on this node-pool

That means you don't **need** to taint-n-tolerate on every pool (eg if you have a 'default pool' where you want  things to run by default (ie if uusers do nothing special to their pods, they will deploy here) and "other pools" for more special/restricted use cases.

This model allows pods to run without any special tweaks to the config rather than tain-n-tolerate everything which means **pods never run if configured without tolerations**.

Depends on your/your user needs, how rigidly locked down you need everything, etc.

As always, there's more than one way to peel the dermis off a feline.